# Does it lead to more maintainable code if I start class fields with an uppercase character in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following:

```
class TransferLink {
    table: string;
    constructor ($link: JQuery) {
        this.table = $link.attr('data-table');
    }
}

class TransferLink {
    Table: string;
    constructor ($link: JQuery) {
        this.Table = $link.attr('data-table');
    }
}
```

I realize Javascript is not C# but I am used to doing all the fields starting with an uppercase. To improve maintainability would it be better to name the fields starting with an uppercase character?

Comment: its probably more about your style of coding. Agreeably, upper case does look more pretty. This is not a coding convertion though like camelize.

Answer (score 8):

I know that the TypeScript team are waiting to see how the language is used in real life before commenting on this topic, but there are two ways to look at this.

Although you are familiar with C#, you probably want to write TypeScript code that interops well with plain JavaScript code, and in plain JavaScript people are used to lower casing on properties and functions. Given that JavaScript is case sensitive, if you are planning on other people using your code you may want to stick with the existing JavaScript convention.

For example...

```
class MyClass {
    myProperty: string;
    myFunction(myParameter: string): void {

    }
}
```

Only the class (and modules) start with an uppercase character.

If you are consuming JSON from various sources, you will have to switch between C# style and JavaScript style in your code as when someone supplied JSON it will almost certainly follow this style - so to avoid the cognetive switch, perhaps the JavaScript style is easiest.

From [Google's JavaScript style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml):

> In general, use functionNamesLikeThis, variableNamesLikeThis,
>   ClassNamesLikeThis, EnumNamesLikeThis, methodNamesLikeThis, and
>   SYMBOLIC_CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS.

Comment: I'm with Steve on this one. Having exactly one naming convention in a codebase is far more important than any personal preference. It's unlikely you'll get very far writing TypeScript before you interface with some JavaScript code that uses methodNameLikeThis naming.

Answer (score 0):

Being both C# and Javascript developer I would say that it's better to name public class fields with uppercase just like it's done in C#. Plus it's very well known that C# influenced TypeScript

Comment: TypeScript seems more influenced by ECMAScript 6 and non-C# object-oriented languages. If you look at interfaces, inheritance and generics, it resembles other languages far more than C#.